# Using ng-selected with a <select>

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to send some piece of information to my `loadSecondary` function, but I don't know how to access any information about my array or the object I'm selecting.

I've tried sending `$index`,`p`,`$parent.$index`,`$parent.p`, and all of them come out as undefined.

What information about my selected object or it's position in the array can I send to my function?

```
<select ng-model="secondPres" ng-options="p.name for p in presentations">
        <option value="" ng-selected="loadSecondary(???)">-- Choose a presentation to merge with --</option>
</select>
```

Comment: `loadSecondary(secondPres)` or `p.name` -- one of those :)

Comment: @tymeJV That didn't seem to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than use ng-selected, I would put a watch on the $scope.secondPres in your controller, then run loadSecondary on it:

```
$scope.$watch('secondPres', function(s) {
    if(typeof s !== 'undefined') {
        $scope.loadSecondary(s);
    }
});
```

Comment: I like this solution better

Answer (score 0):

Since I couldn't send anything with `ng-selected`, I sent nothing.

I ended up just accessing `$scope.secondPres`, from the inside the function